# Build Parameterized Spiral Geometry

Tags: geometry, parametric

I want to Build Parameterized Spiral Geometry.

To offset a constant distant d on a Archimedean spiral.
Like the picture shows
[image: offset d]
The original parametric form of Archimedean Spiral is:
$$x(t) = a\cdot t\cdot \cos(t)$$
$$y(t) = a\cdot t\cdot \sin(t)$$

Then my target new equation which has same period sine waves on Archimedean spiral is :
$$x(t) = (at + \sin(bt^2)) \cos(t)$$
$$y(t) = (at + \sin(bt^2)) \sin(t)$$

I successfully use the equation in the picture above draw a Parameterized Spiral on Desmos:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jerewqqzuc
[image: non_same_period]

My goal is to make a d offset on the spiral which has same period sine wave on it and control the amplitude of the sine wave. Please help me !Thanks!
similar example:
[Equation of sine wave around a spiral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2117251/equation-of-sine-wave-around-a-spiral)

Comment: It's hard to understand what you desire to achieve (in particular, the word "geometry" doesn't look very enlightning) : do you want that **all** (not just one out of 2) your "spiraled sine waves" touch themselves ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> Can you please clarify whether this is the same as [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4179728/control-equation-of-equidistantly-sine-wave-on-archimedean-spiral), and if not what is different?

Comment: The question is the same. Because I think that one is too complicated so I write a new one. 
@AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: My goal is to draw another Archimedean Spiral which has : First, same period sine wave on it. Second, can make a d offset on it. @JeanMarie

Comment: What I have done is : draw a original Archimedean Spiral which has sine waves on it, but not same period. and make a d offset on it so that's why the drawing shows like that. 
@JeanMarie

Comment: Just a note that I've voted to close this as a duplicate of [Control Equation of equidistantly sine wave on Archimedean Spiral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4179728/control-equation-of-equidistantly-sine-wave-on-archimedean-spiral)